# C# DNS.GetHostEntry() .. new programmer new to network programming

Tags: c#

I am really unfamiliar with C#, it's been years since I've programmed with this language. I'm going to post the code I have, which has build errors. This is what I'm trying to do, but I really am not sure how to proceed. I have hit a wall and really have no clue how to proceed:

Enter an address (as a string)
Resolve the address using the appropriate function
Print out the complete host information

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace CSDNS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void PrintHostInfo(String host)
        {
            {
                IPHostEntry hostinfo;

                try
                {

                    hostinfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.sunybroome.edu"); // DNS Name Resolution

                    //
                    // The IP address is now in hostinfo structure
                    // Print out the contents of hostinfo structure
                    // in an easily readable form with labels. For
                    // example, the host name can be output using:


                    Console.WriteLine("Hostname = {0}\n", hostinfo.HostName);
                }

                catch
                {
                    // Print out the exception here...
                }



                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostInfo;

                    //Attempt to resolve DNS for given host or address
                    hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(host);

                    //Display the primary host name
                    Console.WriteLine("\tCanonical Name: " + hostInfo.HostName);

                    //Display list of IP addresses for this host
                    Console.Write("\tIP Addresses:  ");
                    foreach (IPAddress ipaddr in hostInfo.AddressList)
                    {
                        Console.Write(ipaddr.ToString() + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    //Display list of alias names for this host
                    Console.Write("\tAliases:       ");
                    foreach (String alias in hostInfo.Aliases)
                    {
                        Console.Write(alias + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUnable to resolve host: " + host + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Get and print local host info
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Local Host:");
                String localHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                Console.WriteLine("\tHost Name:      " + localHostName);

                PrintHostInfo(localHostName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to resolve local host\n");
            }

            //Get and print info for hosts given on command line 
            foreach (String arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg + ":");
                PrintHostInfo(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like code that was given out for homework with the places marked that you should fill in. What part do you need help with? What have you tried?

Comment: "I'm going to post the code I have, which has build errors." Can you point out exception exactly? I assume you are missing `PrintHostInfo` method which is not framework method.

Comment: let me post some more code that I have.. currently the build errors about are the printhostinfo method, which I don't know if that will even do what I need it to. Thanks for looking and trying to help I really appreciate it!!

Comment: I edited my main code.. I'm having build errors "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Dns.Resolve(string)' has some invalid arguments", "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.IPHostEntry' to 'string'". The end goal is to Enter an address (as a string), Resolve the address using the appropriate function and Print out the complete host information

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in `host` to the `Resolve` method, not `hostInfo` (i.e. the string that contains the host you want to resolve):

```
hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(host);
```

Comment: ok thanks! Now I have zero build errors. I'm supposed to use this though DNS.GetHostEntry() to accomplish below..                 Enter an address (as a string)
Resolve the address using the appropriate function
Print out the complete host information
        If no error was returned, print all host information.
        If an error was returned, print a descriptive error message

Comment: ok, I changed your line to this hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);   ..however the IP address does not change no matter what website I enter?

Comment: Any help guys? I don't know what to do. I think I can trim some of the code I have added, and I'm not sure what to put in the comment section

Comment: @Cliff edit your question to only include relevant code and explain the errors you get and what you are trying to do.